# Qt Designer has no canvas

Tags: qt, qml, qt-designer

The canvas in the Qt Designer has disappeared. Earlier today there was a checkered canvas that represented the application window in my application. At some point this canvas disappeared. This seems to be happening with every project I create.

What have I done wrong?

[image]

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  Am seeing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, no.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with Creator. Try to set the following environment variable and see if you get any interesting output:

`DEBUG_QML_PUPPET=1 ./qtcreator`

If you're feeling adventurous, you can also experiment with setting some of the various debug variables to `true` in the code:

```
micurtis@mitch-ubuntu:~/dev/qt-creator$ git grep "debug = false" | grep designer
src/plugins/qmldesigner/components/integration/designdocument.cpp:    debug = false
src/plugins/qmldesigner/components/propertyeditor/propertyeditorview.cpp:    debug = false
src/plugins/qmldesigner/components/stateseditor/stateseditormodel.cpp:    debug = false
src/plugins/qmldesigner/components/stateseditor/stateseditorwidget.cpp:    debug = false
src/plugins/qmldesigner/designercore/instances/nodeinstanceview.cpp:    debug = false
src/plugins/qmldesigner/designercore/metainfo/metainfo.cpp:    debug = false
src/plugins/qmldesigner/designercore/metainfo/metainforeader.cpp:    debug = false
src/plugins/qmldesigner/designercore/metainfo/subcomponentmanager.cpp:enum { debug = false };
src/plugins/qmldesigner/designmodewidget.cpp:    debug = false
```

Otherwise, please file a bug report against Qt Creator at: https://bugreports.qt-project.org